# Why does React fetch() send 2 requests to the server?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to send an AJAX request to the server via `fetch()`:

```
    fetch('/api/addUserObject', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({...this.state, token: this.props.userData.token, 
      profile: this.props.currentProfile }),
      }).then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
```

When I open the network log in Chrome I see something like this:
[image: screenshot]

So why are there 2 requests instead of 1? They are both accepted on the server side.

This request is handled by an onClick event:

```
<div className="btn" onClick={this.handleSubmit} /></div>
```

The problem is, that this is a POST request and I need to get data in this, so one request (if it sends headers to check for cross origin), initiates an error on the server.

The component code is massive, so I will represent it as:

```
<StyledDiv>
  <FormControl>...</FormControl>
  <FormControl>...</FormControl>
  <FormControl>...</FormControl>
  <FormControl>...</FormControl>
  <div className="btn" onClick={this.handleSubmit} /></div>
</StyiledDiv>
```

Comment: Share your component's code, please. Code you wrote here looks correct

Comment: This must be a OPTIONS request, OPTIONS request is used to check if you are allowed to perform the GET/POST
 request from that domain and what headers can be used for that request.

Comment: @Justcode i also send GET requests, they dont have this issues... and how to handle this if it is accepted on server side and as POST request that should contain data?

Comment: @asiniy, i added some code, there is nothing unusual as i think...

Comment: what server side do you use?

Comment: @Zoltan everything looks nice. Could you create the reproducable example on codesandbox or somewhere else?

Comment: @Justcode, php API, well, i can check for request body to eveluate an error, but why is this even an error, i dont what to respont with error or even send an aditional request to the server in the first place...

Comment: @asiniy here is an example https://codesandbox.io/s/0qm93r303v

Comment: @Zoltan but I see only one request by click....

Comment: @asiniy i see 2, at least first time when i click on the button, try to click it only once with network panel opened, there will be 2 requests, if you clicka after few seconds there will be 2 again, if you click without some pouses it will send 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't aware of why this was happening myself.

I looked up a bit and found out about [preflighted requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests#Preflighted_requests) for a security reasons.

`fetch` will first check the Web API to see if it's safe to send using `OPTION` verb and when it's fine, it sends the request again using your specified verb, `POST` in your case.

[image]

So the issue seems to be specific to how `fetch` handles [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: Is there a way to change this behavior? There are many things going wrong with this )

Answer (score 0):

trying using,

"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
instead of
"Content-Type": "application/json"

It will send a single call, and will not snd the options call